# Adding Element of an Object in an Array in an Array to a String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, loops

I have a method that is suppose to traverse 2 arrays of Ojbects, the first being Menu of size 50, which contains Recipes, which hold up to 10 elements called ingredients, which holds up to 3 elements each, but I am only looking for their names! I want to take the matching names of those Ingredient elements in the Recipes and add them to my String array and then return it, here is my code...

```
public class Recipe implements Cloneable
{

    String Name;

    final int INGREDIENT_ARRAY_MAX = 10;

    Ingredient Ingredients[] = new Ingredient[INGREDIENT_ARRAY_MAX];

    public class RecipeBook
    {

        final static int MENU_ARRAY_MAX = 50;

        static Recipe Menu[] = new Recipe[MENU_ARRAY_MAX];

        public static String[] getRecipesByIngredient(String ingredientName)
        {

            String[] targetRecipes = new String[MENU_ARRAY_MAX];

            int counter = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < Menu.length; j++)
            {

                if (Menu[j] == null)
                {

                    break;

                }

                else
                {

                    for (int k = 0; k < Menu[j].Ingredients.length; k++)
                    {

                        System.out.println(Menu[j].Ingredients[k]);

                        if (Menu[j].Ingredients[k].getName().equals(ingredientName))
                        {

                            targetRecipes[counter] = Menu[j].getName();
                            counter++;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return targetRecipes;

        }
    }
}
```

Now I know it doesn't work and why, but the solution I am not sure about. At the moment I only have 3 Recipes and 3 Ingredients in each recipe! The stuff up top is just for reference, those are the object arrays of RecipeBook (Menu) and Recipes (Ingredients).

Now when ran this code gets me into a NullPointerException because tries testing nulls against Strings, but how could I make it check through the Recipe, if it doesn't find anything, it moves on to the next Recipe in Menu, if it does, it simply adds it but continues to check til finish. I tried adding "if" statements checking for nulls and not nulls but it becomes convoluted and it still doesn't get my program to return to checking the rest of the arrays. I know the first "if" can stay because, well if the spot i check in Menu is null, the rest of it must be null so there's no point in going farther. But how do I check the Ingredients array, find something, add it, and go back to sifting through the Menu for recipes with that ingredient? Is it possible to add an if inside the inner loop to check for null and if it is, just go back to the outer loop?

Comment: First question: why are you using arrays instead of lists?

Comment: required of me, unfortuntely

Answer (score 0):

update  if conditions as below

1st if condition :

if (Menu[j] == null || Menu[j].Ingredients == null || Menu[j].Ingredients.length ==0)

2nd if condition :

if (Menu[j].Ingredients[k] != null && ingredientName.equal(Menu[j].Ingredients[k].getName()))
please let me know if there any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you fill the recipe array but what i can say is that your code is missing a lot of null checks. I would go this way (code not compiled / tested):

```
public static String[] getRecipesByIngredient(String ingredientName) {
    String[] targetRecipes = null;
    // check input parameter ingredientName against null and do lookup only if it is not null
    if(ingredientName != null) {
        // init the result array and do look up
        targetRecipes = new String[MENU_ARRAY_MAX];
        for (int j = 0; j < Menu.length; j++) {
            // you might run into NPE if Menu[j] or if the array of ingredients in Menu[j] (Menu[j].Ingredients) is null
            if(Menu[j] != null && Menu[j].Ingredients != null) {
                for (int k = 0; k < Menu[j].Ingredients.length; k++) {
                    // Menu[j].Ingredients[k] may also be null
                    // Menu[j].Ingredients[k].getName() may also be null but no need to check it since
                    // you call equals of the string object ingredientName witch you already checked
                    // and equals(null) is always false in that case
                    if (Menu[j].Ingredients[k] != null && ingredientName.equals(Menu[j].Ingredients[k].getName()) {
                        // here you might want to check Menu[j].getName() against null otherwise you'll have
                        // a null inside your result array (this is some like a land mine) unless you want
                        // to check against null while iterating over you result array
                        if(Menu[j].getName() != null) {
                            targetRecipes[counter++] = Menu[j].getName();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } // save the else...
        }
    } // else targetRecipes is still null, with witch you may want to say "no result found"
    return targetRecipes;
}
```